# Delete the boot partition

Tags: ntfs, bootloader

Boot configuration is on NTFS partition and I have Ubuntu side-loaded on my computer. I want to delete the NTFS partition completely and format the drive as ext4 file system. But, I assume that deletes the boot loader as well. Please advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting  all the ntfs partitions, run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It will reinstall grub on your disk.